# hope to save NSImage without image size change

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage

what I hope to get is

```
1.load image to a NSImage
2.draw some text on the NSImage
3.save the NSImage to a image file
```

so I used code below to load image to NSImage

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[asset fullFilename]];
NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data] ;
```

if the original image size is

```
imageOriginalWidth, imageOriginalHeight
```

the size(width, height) of img will be smaller than original image size, it means that

```
imgWidth<imageOriginalWidth
imgHeight<imageOriginalHeight
```

it also means that if I save the NSImage with text to a image file, the new image is smaller than the original one

Your comment welcome

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but putting an image into a smaller image view doesn't change the image size.

Comment: `NSImage` doesn't have a `frame` property. Please post your code.